# Postfix rejects incoming mails

Tags: linux, debian, postfix, email-server

```
Dec 13 15:14:11 raspberrypi postfix/smtpd[7702]: connect from mail-wm1-f52.google.com[209.85.128.52]
Dec 13 15:14:11 raspberrypi postfix/smtpd[7702]: warning: connect to Milter service local:/opendkim/opendkim.sock: No such file or directory
Dec 13 15:14:11 raspberrypi postfix/smtpd[7702]: TLS SNI smtp.rbmuanyag.hu from mail-wm1-f52.google.com[209.85.128.52] not matched, using default chain
Dec 13 15:14:11 raspberrypi spawn[7709]: fatal: spawn_comand: execvp /usr/bin/policyd-spf: No such file or directory
Dec 13 15:14:12 raspberrypi postfix/spawn[7708]: warning: command /usr/bin/policyd-spf exit status 1
Dec 13 15:14:13 raspberrypi spawn[7710]: fatal: spawn_comand: execvp /usr/bin/policyd-spf: No such file or directory
Dec 13 15:14:14 raspberrypi postfix/spawn[7708]: warning: command /usr/bin/policyd-spf exit status 1
Dec 13 15:14:14 raspberrypi postfix/smtpd[7702]: warning: problem talking to server private/policyd-spf: Connection reset by peer
Dec 13 15:14:14 raspberrypi postfix/smtpd[7702]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-wm1-f52.google.com[209.85.128.52]: 451 4.3.5 <pupaak@rbmuanyag.hu>: Recipient address rejected: Server configuration problem; from=<ramhapdominik@gmail.com> to=<pupaak@rbmuanyag.hu> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-wm1-f52.google.com>
Dec 13 15:14:14 raspberrypi postfix/smtpd[7702]: disconnect from mail-wm1-f52.google.com[209.85.128.52] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 bdat=0/1 quit=1 commands=5/7
```

So, I have a problem, where postfix is rejecting every incoming mail. If I test it with mailutils, it will receive it, no problem.

My mail.info is at the top.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in configuration. Looks like opendkim milter is not started or wrongly configured spf too.

Please check if those services are running and sockets are created